# Formula to have a result in a column if the entered value is in between the two column list

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to put a formula to figure out a particular cell in a column if the desired value is between two columns. Like if i put a value of 120, the result should show "8", as it is in range of 111 & 124.

[image: Lookup table]

Comment: Are the values in the first 2 columns non overlapping always?

Answer (score 2):

As the two value lists you are comparing against are contiguous (i.e. the second row in column A is one more than the first row column B) you could use an `MATCH` function on column A without looking at either of the other columns.

```
=MATCH(120,$A$1:$A$10,1)
```

The last argument `1` specifies return the position of the number in the list that is less than the search criteria provided the list is sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that as shown in your snapshot, the first 2 column values are non overlapping, you can try this Array Formula.

Sample data is in Cells C3:E7, C & D being first two columns. Enter search value in G3.
Put the following formula in I3.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E3:E7,MIN(IF(G3>=C3:C7,IF(G3<=D3:D7,ROW(C3:C7)-ROW(C2),9^99),9^99))),"Not Found")
```

Now press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the Formula Bar to create an Array Formula. The formula shall be automatically enclosed in curly braces to indicate that it's an array formula.

Note the following

- Leave at least one row free above the table to refer the ROW function in Excel
- If you are using Excel version prior to 2007 then remove the outer IFERROR. It may not be available. It just replaces Error with 'Not Found' text.
- Row(C2) is important in above example, adjust to refer the one previous row before the table in your solution.

[image]